# issue with CustomView drawing in my application

Tags: android, view, custom-view

What is wrong in my code here.why it is not drawing my customview on screen.

```
class CustActivty extends Activty{
private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;;
Path path;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.imagelayout);
CustomView view=new CustomView(getApplicationContext());
RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
rl.addView(view);
}


class CustomView extends View{

CustomView(Context context){
```

super(context);
    path=new Path();
    RectF rec=new RectF(10,10,400,400);

```
path.addArc(rec,90,180);

mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new PathShape(path,400,400));
mDrawable.setBounds(10, 10, 400,400);
mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
}
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
 mDrawable.draw(canvas);

}
}
}
```

Plz anybody having idea.Plz help.

Comment: try `setContentView(view)` forget about `rl`.. tell me if it draws

Comment: yes it is drawing without relativelayout.what is the problem with relativelayout then?

Comment: You have to `rl.addView(view, params);` `params` should be defined as `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`

Comment: It works thanks.Put it as answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the `LayoutParams` that your `view` will use to be added to the `RelativeLayout`

So instead of just `rl.addView(view)`

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = //initialise them as you want
rl.addView(view, params);
```

Comment: one question.If we are not specifying any layoutparams then it shud take any default params right ? but it is not taking.why ?

Comment: I think your CustomView is a very raw class. You might have not dealt with width and height. So, if the default is a `WRAP_CONTENT` your view might be getting a zero width and height. I am just guessing. Not sure.